# How to sort numbers in excel 2013

Tags: sorting, excel-2013

I have an excel file that holds a column with data in numbers, when I try to sort it, it's sorted like this:

original list:
1,99,1011,33122,4589,330

sorted now:
1,1011,330,33122,4589,99

need to be sorted like this:
1,99,330,1011,4589,33122

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Select a single cell from the column you want to sort.
2. On the Data tab, in the Sort and filter group, click. to rank in ascending order (from A to Z or from the smallest to the largest number).
3. Click on. to sort in descending order (from Z to A or from the largest to the smallest number).